# Importance of Pydoop in BigData Analytics and Data Science

Tags: python, pandas, hadoop, data-science

I am new to Data Science and Big Data Frameworks.
Lets say,I have a DataSet input in CSV.
What I found from Google and other resources about a Data Analyst and Data Scientist daily job,

- Once user gets DataSet, first will manipulate with help of python pandas library which includes Data cleaning and other stuffs.
- Then User visualizes the datas using matplotlib and other techniques.
- User can write Machine Learning algorithms to get a prediction for some criterias.

All the above workflows can be summarized into data analysis and prediction.

Now, on the other account, I found out Pydoop(a Hadoop framework of Python) to 
do operations like Storage, processing etc

I am bit confused, in the Data Analysis workflow mentioned above where pydoop stands exactly in that?

Please guide me.

Comment: Not really a StackOverflow question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Anyway, as already answered by cricket_007, Pydoop is a tool for interacting with Hadoop (both HDFS and MapReduce) in Python, rather than the native Java.

Answer (score 0):

Pydoop isn't a framework. The documentation says it's an interface into the MapReduce framework

> Pydoop is a Python interface to Hadoop that allows you to write MapReduce applications in pure Python

With some more research, you'll find more examples of **PySpark** than `pydoop` and writing plain MapReduce isn't exactly easy (although easier in Python than Java), and not really meant for Data Scientists

In any case, the mentioned workflow, the user needs to get "the Dataset". It could be stored in Hadoop, and `pydoop` would be able to process it (via MapReduce applications), however, that's not going to be done very easily with `pandas`, as pandas requires all the data locally to create a dataframe, not streamed in line-by-line from a remote filesystem.

`pydoop` also does not natively offer any Machine learning algorithms, compared to PySpark, so again doesn't apply to the workflow.

PySpark has a `toPandas` function that is the gateway between Hadoop processes and "standalone" Pandas applications for data science and visualizations, however Jupyter and Apache Zeppelin are more commonly used to do Spark visualizations directly without needing to interface with Pandas.